# Error when trying to access a 2d Array in PHP

Tags: php

I have written a couple pages and some function to turn a .csv file into an array, after which I will be using the array to access and use the data. Most of the code is in place and works but I am stuck with trying to access the fields I want.

The code to create the array looks like this:

```
//code for accepting and checking the uploaded file
if($ext === 'csv'){
        if(($handle = fopen($tmpName, 'r')) !== FALSE) {


            set_time_limit(0);

            //index
            $row = 0;

            while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
                // number of fields in the csv
                $num = count($data);
                /*echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";*/

                // get the values from the csv
                $csv[$row]['row1'] = $data[0];
                $csv[$row]['row2'] = $data[1];
                $csv[$row]['row3'] = $data[2];
                $csv[$row]['row4'] = $data[3];

                //increment 
                $row++;
            }

            print_array($csv[1][0]);
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
```

And when I call something like `print_array($csv[1];` The result is:

```
Array
(
    [row1] => DataOne
    [row1] => DataTwo
    [row1] => DataThree
    [row1] => DataFour
)
```

But when I call `print_array($csv[1][1]);` I get the error: `Notice: Undefined Offset: 1 On line *and so on*`

Everything I have read makes it seem like this should work. I can't figure out how to get access to what I need. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact output of the array? I don't think that's possible, each key must be unique in an array so you can't have two `row1` keys.  And to access that you would do this: `$csv[1]['row1']`.

Comment: You can call the array elements like this: `echo $row[0]["row1"];`

Comment: Dan you are right, the should say row2 and so on.I just copy/pasted when I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check how many elements your Array have looks to me like it just read the first line and your Array length is 1.

```
echo("Array count: ".count($csv));
```